# Air lock blow out

Tags: fermentation

This is my first time to brew. This morning when I checked the fermenter I noticed the airlock had blown off. I reinstalled it and cleaned up the mess. Will this lead to any contamination in my brew

Comment: In addition to the answers below, if this becomes a regular occurrence a blow off tube will minimize your fermentation clean up duties.

Comment: Relax, don't worry, have a homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

A blown airlock is most usually due to a vigorous fermentation and a lack of head space above the brew in the fermentation vessel. The airlock becomes clogged and the build up of pressure blows the bung. It is not an uncommon event but one that should be checked for - by leaving sufficient space over the brew in the fermenting vessel. Sometimes cooling will also help lessen the vigour of the fermentation.

Chances are that the beer will be fine. Many brewers brew beer in a brew bin without an airlock so temporarily not having one is not immediately fatal to a brew. It is true that infections can enter in such a manner but I would advise continuing the fermentation and to bottle/keg the beer as normal. It is not impossible that it could turn out badly but it is more probable that it will be OK. Only time and tasting will tell! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It should be okay. If the airlock got blown out by co2, that means that there is a nice headspace of co2 above your brew. Most bacteria won't be able to live in co2 so your brew should be all good. Let it ferment further and only start worrying if you see signs of infection.

Comment: You're right about most bacteria won't survive a harsh environment as beer (CO2, alcohol, hop acids, etc...), but there is a well known bacteria in the homebrewers world that produces diacetyl and is an anaerobic organism, the Lactobacillus.

Comment: I think yeasts will also produce diactyl and acetoin at stages in normal fermentation.